# SQL statement won't insert into DB.sdf

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-ce

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and have connected a database correctly as I have done a login that works fine, although when I try to insert information submitted in the text boxes a different table, it doesn't enter after I end program to check it still has no data in. Any ideas?

```
    Dim con As SqlCeConnection = New SqlCeConnection("Data Source=NESdb.sdf")        
    Dim myDA As SqlCeDataAdapter
    Dim myDataSet As DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable()        

    'Connect to database'
    con.Open()
    'Attempt to retrieve data'
    Try ' Select username and password that match'
        Dim cmd As SqlCeDataAdapter = New SqlCeDataAdapter("INSERT INTO ScrapVehicles(Fname, Lname, Add1, Add2, Town, PostCode, Telephone, Mob, Email, VehicleType, RegNo, Year, Make, Model, V5, Collected, CollectionDate)" + "VALUES('" & txtFname.Text & "', '" & txtLname.Text & "', '" & txtAdd1.Text & "', '" & txtAdd2.Text & "', '" & txtTown.Text & "', '" & txtPostCode.Text & "', '" & txtTelephone.Text & "', '" & txtMob.Text & "', '" & txtEmail.Text & "', '" & comboVehicleType.Text & "', '" & txtReg.Text & "', '" & comboYear.Text & "', '" & comboMake.Text & "', '" & txtModel.Text & "', '" & chkV5.Text & "', '" & chkCollected.Text & "', '" & dtpWhen.Text & "')", con)
        'Catch errors'
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    'Close connection to database'
    If con.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
        con.Close()
    End If
```

Comment: Updated with the whole form info.

Comment: hope you don't mind - I've cut out the code that isn't relevant. If in the future you need to paste lots of code, use pastebin.com or similar. Just the relevant parts :)

Comment: Thank you Campbell, I will try your suggestions and greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're building up the `cmd` object, but you don't execute it.

Suggest ditch the Adapter when inserting. Try this instead:

```
/*snipped values for brevity.*/
Dim insertSql As String = "INSERT INTO ScrapVehicles(Fname, Lname, Add1, Add2, Town) VALUES(@FName, @LName, @Add1, @Add2, @Town)" 

conn.Open()
Dim cmd As New SqlCeCommand(insertSql, conn)
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@FName", txtFirstName.Text.Trim()))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@LName", txtLastName.Text.Trim()))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@Add1", txtAdd1.Text.Trim()))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlCeParameter("@Add2", txtAdd2.Text.Trim()))

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a bracket at the end

`& dtpWhen.Text & "'", con)`

should be

`& dtpWhen.Text & "')", con)`

Comment: Thanks Barry, I shall give it a try (Y)

Comment: No lucky barry, still need help :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a [SqlCeDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcedataadapter.sqlcedataadapter(v=VS.80).aspx), use a [SqlCeCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand(v=VS.80).aspx) object. And after creating it, actually use it (call [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.executenonquery(v=VS.80).aspx) on it). And remove the Try, Catch Ex as Exception and End Try lines so that, *if an error occurs*, you'll actually see it.

That's what I can see from 30 seconds of looking.

*Edit*

You should also look at using [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.commandtext(v=VS.80).aspx) rather than concatenating the INSERT statement together.